# Error when trying to fetch single document from firestore in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2, angularfire

I think I'm making some silly mistake when trying to create a function to get a single document's data from firestore in Angular.

```
public async getPage(id){
    const ref = this.db.collection('pages').doc(id).get().data();
  }
```

This was my original code. I hadn't gone further than the fetch because I got the error:
`Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Observable<DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>>'`

I also tried the following, with the same error:

```
public async getPage(id){
    const ref = await this.db.collection('pages').doc(id).get().data();
  }
```

```
public async getPage(id){
     const result = await this.db.collection('pages').doc(id).get()
     console.log(result.data())
}
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either subscribe to the observable `get()` or convert into a promise using `toPromise()` to await the call.

```js
export class PageServices {
  public getPage(id: string) {
    this.db.collection('pages').doc(id).get().subscribe((res => {
      console.log(res.data());
    }));
  }

  // or using `toPromise`
  public async getPageAsync(id: string) {
    const docSnapshot = await this.db.collection('pages').doc(id).get().toPromise();
    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      console.log(docSnapshot.data());
    }
  }
}
```